# GoogleMaps for iOS sluggish redraw

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have googlemaps in my app as I am using some Google API and have to display it on googlemaps as past of their terms of service.

The issue I have is drawing a polyline, and adding annotations for bus stops, when zooming in or out the app is sluggish and lags as it tries to redraw the info. Where as on MapKit there is no issue.

Is this a normal issue with Googlemaps being less responsive?

Comment: I'm using version 1.5 and should tell it is on par and may be a bit faster than MKMapView, memory consumption is on par as well. Though in higher versions there are certain bugs that keep me from using it, so I can't tell if performance is not one of those ingredients that unfortunately degraded in Google's iOS map over time. Pace of bug fixing is definitely slower than it used to be :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved updating to 1.9.0, FPS stayed above 28 on iphone 6, where the previous version 1.8.0 would drop to 5FPS.